# Datatables plugin returns this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, laravel, datatables

Hey guys i have a probem, i'm using datatables plugin with the serverside, and the ajax request response with this error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data i realy don't know why the json is invalid 
i'm using laravel and in the controller you can see this code

```
public function gestionParticipant($id){
        $participant = Participant::all()->whereIn('event_id',$id);
        return DataTables::of($participant)
        ->addColumn('Adherent',function($participant){
            return ''.$participant->participantAdherent->first_name.'';
        })
        ->addColumn('Participant',function($participant){
            return ''.$participant->nom_participant.' '.$participant->nom_participant.'';
        })
        ->addColumn('Payeur',function($id){
            $payeur = Payeur::all()->whereIn('event_id',$id);
            return ''.$payeur->nom_payeur.' '.$payeur->prenom_payeur.'';
        })
        ->addColumn('Montant',function(){

        })
        ->addColumn('Presence',function(){

        });
    }
```

i'm trying to show the datatable in a bootstrap modal
and here's the javascript in the view

```
$('#table').on('click','.showModal',function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#tableModal').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": "/admin/evenment/event/participant/ajax_gestion_participant/"+id,
                "columns":[
                    {"data":"Adherent"},
                    {"data":"Participant"},
                    {"data":"Payeur"},
                    {"data":null},
                    {"data":null},
                ]
            });
        $('#gestionModal').modal('show');
```

plz help

Comment: Which is the plugin? what is returning ->addColumn('',function(){}); ??

Comment: i forgot the ->make(true); at the end x)